# Getting the last entry in a named range in excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

After copying a template sheet via vba I need to set two cells for start and end dates that use  data validation referencing a sheet scoped named range for its formula. To do this I need the first and last entries for the named range.

To test the code before setting the cell data I have the following:

`Debug.Print "Charts 1 Start " & Sh.Names("ProjectTemplateDates").RefersToRange(1, 1)`

`Debug.Print "Charts 1 End " & Sh.Names("ProjectTemplateDates").RefersToRange.End(xlDown).Value`

The first Debug.Print gives me the correct first entry:

`Charts 1 Start 01/09/2017`

however the last entry code gives me:

`Charts 1 End 100000`

When I was expecting it to give me **Charts 1 End 01/03/2023**. Should I be doing something different to find the last entry in the named range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With sh.Names("ProjectTemplateDates").RefersToRange
    Debug.Print "Charts 1 Start " & .Cells(1, 1)
    
    Debug.Print "Charts 1 End " & .Cells(.Rows.Count + 1, 1).End(xlUp).Value
End With
```

Comment: I think this would have worked if the data was in row format (something I forgot) so I ended up with the following working solution for the column based named range - `Debug.Print "Charts 1 End" & .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Value`

Comment: @AutomationMonkey: If data are on a single row, then use: Debug.Print "Charts 1 End" & .Cells(1, .Columns.Count + 1).End(xlToLeft).Value